# Building & executing queries using stored procedure - with multiple rows returned & stored in each variable

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, execute

I am attempting to create a stored procedure, which is expected to perform the following:

1. Return the selected values from a table (`DWH_ALM_ST_AUDIT_TRAIL_MAP`) and insert into variables
2. The values returned are parts of a SQL statement
3. Execute the SQL statement built

I have tested out to print in Script Output, using `DBS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE`, and the results look fair. However, when I try to execute the procedure (not print) - the result prompt successful, but no updates were made despite rows matching the conditions.

To better illustrate, you may refer to the code and sample data below.

I have created the SQL statement below:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE SP_GET_ROW_NUM
AS
/* cursor used to store multiple rows of values in a variable */
    CURSOR ROW_NUM_CUR IS
        SELECT  ROW_NUM
        FROM    DWH_ALM_ST_AUDIT_TRAIL_MAP;

    CURSOR QUERY_CUR IS
        SELECT  QUERY
        FROM    DWH_ALM_ST_AUDIT_TRAIL_MAP;

    ROW_t ROW_NUM_CUR%ROWTYPE;
    TYPE ROW_ntt IS TABLE OF ROW_t%TYPE; 
    l_ROW  ROW_ntt;

    QUERY_t QUERY_CUR%ROWTYPE;
    TYPE QUERY_ntt IS TABLE OF QUERY_t%TYPE; 
    l_QUERY  QUERY_ntt;

    SQL_STAT VARCHAR2(2000);

BEGIN
    OPEN  ROW_NUM_CUR;
    FETCH ROW_NUM_CUR BULK COLLECT INTO l_ROW;
    CLOSE ROW_NUM_CUR;

    OPEN  QUERY_CUR;
    FETCH QUERY_CUR BULK COLLECT INTO l_QUERY;
    CLOSE QUERY_CUR;

    FOR i IN 1..l_ROW.COUNT LOOP
        SQL_STAT := 'UPDATE DWH_ALM_GAP_STRESS_TEST SET ROW_NUM = ' || l_ROW(i).ROW_NUM || ' ' || l_QUERY(i).QUERY || ';' ;

    END LOOP;

END SP_GET_ROW_NUM;
```

This is the sample data:

`DWH_ALM_ST_AUDIT_TRAIL_MAP`:

| ROW_NUM | QUERY |
| --- | --- |
| 45 | WHERE TOP_CONVENTION = 'CAISSE TITRES' AND PERIMETRE = 'I. EXTERNE' |
| 46 | WHERE TOP_CONVENTION = 'BRUT' AND PERIMETRE = 'II. EXTERNE OCAA' |

Really appreciate it if someone could advise on this.

Happy to share more if required.

Comment: Hi.  Where do you believe your statement is that actually executes the SQL statement that you're building in your loop?  Yes, you are populating the SQL_STAT object with a string that is build based on the rows you are looping over.  But how do you think that statement gets executed?  Simply setting the value of a variable does not actually execute the UPDATE

Answer (score 0):

Included the missing `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` function and everything works well now!

```
    create or replace PROCEDURE SP_GET_ROW_NUM
AS
    CURSOR ROW_NUM_CUR IS
        SELECT  ROW_NUM
        FROM    DWH_ALM_ST_AUDIT_TRAIL_MAP;

    CURSOR QUERY_CUR IS
        SELECT  QUERY
        FROM    DWH_ALM_ST_AUDIT_TRAIL_MAP;

    ROW_t ROW_NUM_CUR%ROWTYPE;
    TYPE ROW_ntt IS TABLE OF ROW_t%TYPE; -- must use type
    l_ROW  ROW_ntt;

    QUERY_t QUERY_CUR%ROWTYPE;
    TYPE QUERY_ntt IS TABLE OF QUERY_t%TYPE; -- must use type
    l_QUERY  QUERY_ntt;

    SQL_STAT VARCHAR2(2000);

BEGIN
    OPEN  ROW_NUM_CUR;
    FETCH ROW_NUM_CUR BULK COLLECT INTO l_ROW;
    CLOSE ROW_NUM_CUR;

    OPEN  QUERY_CUR;
    FETCH QUERY_CUR BULK COLLECT INTO l_QUERY;
    CLOSE QUERY_CUR;

    FOR i IN 1..l_ROW.COUNT LOOP
        SQL_STAT := 'UPDATE DWH_ALM_GAP_STRESS_TEST SET ROW_NUM = ' || l_ROW(i).ROW_NUM || ' ' || l_QUERY(i).QUERY;
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SQL_STAT;

    END LOOP;

END SP_GET_ROW_NUM;
```